# How to set load next page data from data in Android

Tags: android, json

I want develop android application for one website. I read website posts from json and show its in RecyclerView every 10 posts and when user scrolling on RecyclerView show more 10 post and go to end! in this project i use `okHTTP v3` and `RecyclerView`!
Json link : [JSON LINK](http://tellfa.com/tafrihgah/?json=get_posts&page=1)
I can load first 10 posts. i want when scrolling on RecyclerView show next 10 post, but show me again first 10 post!

**MainActivity codes:**

```
public class Main_page extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final long RIPPLE_DURATION = 250;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private RelativeLayout root;
    private ImageView menu_image;
    private RecyclerView main_recyclerView;
    private MainAdapter2 mAdaper;
    private List<MainDataModel> dataModels = new ArrayList<MainDataModel>();
    private List<MainDataModel> dataModelsArray;
    private Context context;
    protected Handler handler;
    private RelativeLayout loadLayout;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private int pageCount = 1;
    private String ServerAddress = ServerIP.getIP();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_page);
        if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) {
            EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        }
        handler = new Handler();
        context = getApplicationContext();
        loadLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_empty_layout);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
        }
        LoadData(pageCount);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        // Menu
        root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_root);
        View guillotineMenu = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, null);
        root.addView(guillotineMenu);
        menu_image = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_logo);
        new GuillotineAnimation.GuillotineBuilder(guillotineMenu, guillotineMenu.findViewById(R.id.menu_layout_image), menu_image)
                .setStartDelay(RIPPLE_DURATION)
                .setActionBarViewForAnimation(toolbar)
                .setClosedOnStart(true)
                .build();
        // RecyclerView and setData
        main_recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.main_recycler);
        main_recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        main_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mAdaper = new MainAdapter2(this, main_recyclerView, dataModels);
        main_recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdaper);

        mAdaper.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                dataModels.add(null);
                mAdaper.notifyItemInserted(dataModels.size() - 1);
                LoadData(pageCount);
            }
        });
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onEvent(List<MainDataModel> mainInfoModels) {
        if (dataModels.size() > 0) {
            dataModels.remove(dataModels.size() - 1);
            mAdaper.notifyItemRemoved(dataModels.size());
            mAdaper.setLoaded();
        }

        mAdaper.add(mainInfoModels);
        mAdaper.notifyDataSetChanged();
        ++pageCount;

        if (dataModels.isEmpty()) {
            main_recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            loadLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            main_recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            loadLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private void LoadData(int pageNumber) {
        MainDataInfo dataInfo = new MainDataInfo();
        // here getMainDataInfo() should return the server response
        dataInfo.getMainDataInfo(this, pageNumber);
    }
}
```

**AsyncTask code:**

```
public class MainDataInfo {
    private Context mContext;
    private String ServerAddress = ServerIP.getIP();

    public void getMainDataInfo(Context context, int pageNumber) {
        mContext = context;
        new getInfo().execute(ServerAddress + "page=" + pageNumber);
    }

    private class getInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();
        private String ou_response;
        private List<MainDataModel> infoModels;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            CustomProcessDialog.createAndShow(mContext);
            infoModels = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(ServerAddress + "page=1")
                    .cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK)
                    .build();

            Response response;
            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                ou_response = response.body().string();
                response.body().close();
                if (ou_response != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject postObj = new JSONObject(ou_response);
                        JSONArray postsArray = postObj.optJSONArray("posts");
                        infoModels = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (int i = 0; i <= infoModels.size(); i++) {
                            JSONObject postObject = (JSONObject) postsArray.get(i);
                            JSONObject images = postObject.optJSONObject("thumbnail_images");
                            JSONObject imagesPair = images.optJSONObject("medium");

                            int id = postObject.getInt("id");
                            String title = postObject.getString("title");
                            String content = postObject.getString("content");
                            String thumbnail = imagesPair.getString("url");
                            Log.d("Data", "Post id: " + id);
                            Log.d("Data", "Post title: " + title);
                            Log.d("Data", "Post title: " + thumbnail);

                            //Use the title and id as per your requirement
                            infoModels.add(new MainDataModel(id, title, content, thumbnail));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return ou_response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            CustomProcessDialog.dissmis();
            if (result != null) {
                bus.post(infoModels);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can show next 10 post when scrolling on `RecyclerView` instance of show again first 10 post?

Answer (score 0):

I checked your JSON , and when you increase page number there is no result. Please fix it first to show your results in your app.

While [this one](http://tellfa.com/tafrihgah/?json=get_posts&page=1) returning you 10 post

When you set your [page number 2](http://tellfa.com/tafrihgah/?json=get_posts&page=2) , it is not returning any post, this is why you are seeing everytime first 10 post.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Emir, i fix it please see this link : http://tellfa.com/tafrihgah/?json=get_posts&page=2 . is it true?

Comment: No my friend, you are getting your json with pagination on your app by increasing page numbers. But in your json api, it is only returning you results for page number = 1.

Comment: You should use your api like this `http://tellfa.com/tafrihgah/?json=get_posts&page=1&limit=10` and can increase your limit value instead of page number 10 by 10

Comment: I use this link `http://tellfa.com/tafrihgah/?json=get_posts&limit=10&page=1` and set page number++ but show again first 10 posts!

Comment: You will not set page number ++, instead of page number you need to increase limit 10 by 10 and need to pass limit value in your http request

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make different pages. One page have data of only 10 blogs. To get information about, Request JSON fro next page when 10th item is shown.
To get item shown info you can use layoutManager.findLastVisbleItem() or lastComletlyVisibleItem().

once requested data is downloaded. There must be method like onRequestComleted() in Volley. notifysetChanged there.

Comment: I use OkHTTP library, can you send me true code? Because i am amateur